# How to find array index relative to the position in matrix?

Tags: arrays, matlab, math, matrix, pseudocode

I had a 2D array (matrix) and its array(1D) representation, I want to know what is the relationship between the **[x][y]** position of an item in matrix with **[index]** of the corresponding item array representation.

**Explanation:**
Lets say I had matrix of 3x4 size:

```
Matrix = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8],[9,10,11,12]]
Array = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

The position of item `'6'` in matrix is `[1][1]` and its position in array is `[5]`.

So what I want to know is what is the relationship b/w `[1][1]` and `[5]` in matrix of size `3x4`.

Thanks for the suggestions and replies.

**PS: I need the mathamatic logic behind it, not a function in any languages (matlab) to do this functionality.**

Comment: Important: MATLAB **or** r? The answer is not the same.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Thanks for the query, I need the algoritham or just mathamatical relationaship, not code on matlab or r.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MATLAB indexes values column-wise, starting at position 1, not zero. Thus in a matrix:

```
A =
     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12

A(:).'   %// Straighten it out to column vector and transpose (to make it a row) 
ans =
     1     5     9     2     6    10     3     7    11     4     8    12
```

So, `A(1) = 1`, `A(2) = 5` etc. If you have a linear index, for instance 7, `A(7) = 3`, and want the indexes on the form [row , col], you can use [`sub2ind`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) like this:

```
ind = 7
[row, col] = ind2sub(size(A), ind)
row =
     1
col =
     3
```

If you want to go the other way, use [`ind2sub`](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html):

```
ind = sub2ind(size(A),row,col)
ind =

     7
```

If you want to use linear indexes and get the result [1 2 3 4 5 ...], you will have to transpose the matrix:

```
B = A.'
B(1:4)
B =
     1     5     9
     2     6    10
     3     7    11
     4     8    12
ans =
     1     2     3     4
```

The logic of `ind2sub` is:

Tell `ind2sub` how many rows and columns a matrix have, i.e. `size(A)`. In this case 3 and 4. Then give ind2sub a linear index (which you seem to know what is). Then what it basically does is:

```
row = mod((ind-1), size(A,1))+1  %// size(A,1) is the number of rows
row =
     1
col = ceil(ind/size(A,1))  %// size(A,2) is the number of columns
col =
     3
```

To illustrate with a last example:

```
A = zeros(2,3);
ind = 1:numel(A);
row = mod((ind-1), size(A,1))+1 
col = ceil(ind/size(A,1))
row =
     1     2     1     2     1     2
col =
     1     1     2     2     3     3

[row col] = ind2sub(size(A),ind)
row =
     1     2     1     2     1     2
col =
     1     1     2     2     3     3
```

Comment: Thats it. Thanks man. The last section. Thats the one I was looking for.

Comment: Can you please tell me the logic of the reverse? Means finding the array index using matrix position? It will be great if you explained me that too.